# Ingest several types of CSV's with Databricks Auto Loader

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to load several types of csv files using Autoloader, it currently merge all csv that I drop into a big parquet table, what I want is to create parquet tables for each type of schema/csv_file

Current code does:
[image: What I currently have]

```
#Streaming files/ waiting a file to be dropped
spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles") \
  .option("cloudFiles.format", "csv") \
  .option("delimiter", "~|~") \
  .option("cloudFiles.inferColumnTypes","true") \
  .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", pathCheckpoint) \
  .load(sourcePath) \
  .writeStream \
  .format("delta") \
  .option("mergeSchema", "true") \
  .option("checkpointLocation", pathCheckpoint) \
  .start(pathResult)
```

What I want [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create different autoloader streams for each file from the same source directory and filter the filenames to consume by using the **pathGlobFilter** option on Autoloader ([databricks documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/ingestion/auto-loader/options.html)). By doing that you will end up having different checkpoints for each table and you can have the different schemas working.

This solution is similar to the one pointed here [How to filter files in Databricks Autoloader stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69663522/how-to-filter-files-in-databricks-autoloader-stream).