# How to filter files in Databricks Autoloader stream

Tags: pyspark, stream, databricks, glob, databricks-autoloader

I want to set up an S3 stream using [Databricks Auto Loader](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/auto-loader-s3.html#configuration-1). I have managed to set up the stream, but my S3 bucket contains different type of JSON files. I want to filter them out, preferably in the stream itself rather than using a `filter` operation.

According to [the docs](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/auto-loader-s3.html#use-cloudfiles-source) I should be able to filter using a glob pattern. However, I can't seem to get this to work as it loads everything anyhow.

This is what I have

```py
df = (
  spark.readStream
  .format("cloudFiles")
  .option("cloudFiles.format", "json")
  .option("cloudFiles.inferColumnTypes", "true")
  .option("cloudFiles.schemaInference.samleSize.numFiles", 1000)
  .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", "dbfs:/auto-loader/schemas/")
  .option("includeExistingFiles", "true")
  .option("multiLine", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
#   .option("cloudFiles.schemaHints", schemaHints)
#  .load("s3://<BUCKET>/qualifier/**/*_INPUT")
  .load("s3://<BUCKET>/qualifier")
  .withColumn("filePath", F.input_file_name())
  .withColumn("date_ingested", F.current_timestamp())
)
```

My files have a key that is structured as `qualifier/version/YYYY-MM/DD/<NAME>_INPUT.json`, so I want to filter files that contain the name input.

This seems to load everything: `.load("s3://<BUCKET>/qualifier")` and `.load("s3://<BUCKET>/qualifier/**/*_INPUT")` is what I want to do, but that doesn't work. (I have also tried `.load("s3://<BUCKET>/qualifier/**/*_INPUT.json"`)

Is my glob pattern incorrect, or is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/auto-loader.html#common-data-loading-patterns), it seems that you can use both load and the pathGlobfilter option to achieve what you need. Have you tried something like this approach here?

```py
df = (
  spark.readStream
  .format("cloudFiles")
  .option("cloudFiles.format", "json")
  .option("cloudFiles.inferColumnTypes", "true")
  .option("cloudFiles.schemaInference.samleSize.numFiles", 1000)
  .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", "dbfs:/auto-loader/schemas/")
  .option("includeExistingFiles", "true")
  .option("multiLine", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .option("pathGlobfilter", "*_INPUT.json") 
  .load("s3://<BUCKET>/qualifier/")
  .withColumn("filePath", F.input_file_name())
  .withColumn("date_ingested", F.current_timestamp())
)
```